# in that query i want inprogress=0 records how to do that

Tags: sql

```
SELECT   access,   count(*) 
from   visitors 
where   type of visitor = 'complaint'   
  and access = 'open'   
   or access = 'inprogress'   
   or access = 'onhold'   
   or access = 'closed'   
   and apartmentid = 72 
group by   access 
order by   access desc
```

Comment: Hi @MadhuSudhan first can you please tag a database you use? Then try please to explain what is exactly that you need. Maybe if you change `access = 'inprogress'`  to `access <>  'inprogress' ` will do what you need. On second look you can remove that line...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't understand what YOU mean by the title and why your query (if fixed) would not do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove `inprogress` filter or do aggregation :

```
SELECT v.access, SUM(CASE WHEN v.access = 'inprogress' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Cnt
FROM visitors v
WHERE v.typeofvisitor = 'complaint' AND
      v.access IN ('complaint', 'open', 'inprogress', 'onhold', 'closed') AND
      v.apartmentid = 72
GROUP BY v.access
ORDER BY v.access;
```

`OR` Can be shorthanded with `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for your problem..

```
 SELECT   access,   count(*) 
    FROM visitors 
    WHERE type of visitor = 'complaint'   
      AND (access = 'open'   
       OR access != 'inprogress'   
       OR access = 'onhold'   
       OR access = 'closed')   
       AND apartmentid = 72 
    GROUP BY access 
    ORDER BY access desc
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense to select or not. It would mean he can delete the whole access selection because it will return true everything that is not inprogress.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select where access = ... and inprogress = 0 the query would be:

```
SELECT   access,   count(*) 
from   visitors 
where   type of visitor = 'complaint'   
  and (access = 'open'   
   or access = 'inprogress'   
   or access = 'onhold'   
   or access = 'closed')   
   and apartmentid = '72' 
   and inprogress = '0'
group by   access 
order by   access desc
```

or only for the access = inprogress case:

```
SELECT   access,   count(*) 
from   visitors 
where   type of visitor = 'complaint'   
  and (access = 'open'   
   or (access = 'inprogress' and inprogress = '0')   
   or access = 'onhold'   
   or access = 'closed')   
   and apartmentid = '72'
group by   access 
order by   access desc
```

Comment: why downvote? I answered to the question he asked, don't see how it is less of an answer?